# Cryptoanalysis using Frequency Analysis

Tags: cryptanalysis, substitution-cipher, ciphertext-only-attack, frequency-analysis

I have read some documents to decrypt ciphertext without a key using Frequency analysis. here are my questions:

- If the most occurring Char is not 'E' then how do we start?
- Let's say I have  this ciphertext

  MLD BLF PMLD GSV TZNV SLD GL KOZB RG. TVG
      IVZWB ULI HRNROZI KILYOVNH RM BLFI VCZNH.
      XSVVIH.

Here is its decrypted text: **now you know the game how to play it. Get ready for similar problems in your exams. cheers**

can someone please help me to sort this out, here most occurring is 'L' but it is not 'E'. 'L' is 'o' here ... I am very confused.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48380/how-to-determine-the-shift-key-to-decrypt-a-ciphertext-which-was-encrypted-using

Comment: You might find it instructive to read Alan Turing's primer on using elementary probability theory to break historical ciphers: [Alan M. Turing, ‘The Applications of Probability Theory to Cryptography’, arXiv:1505.04714](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04714), modern typeset of [Bletchley Park manuscript in UK National Archives, Reference HW 25/37](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C11510465).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a monoalphabetic substitution cipher - the same letter in the plaintext will always be represented as a identical letter in the ciphertext (for example the plaintext-letter "E" is always a "V" in the ciphertext).

---

**Frequency analysis works better the longer the text is.** For very short texts (as yours) it can be very difficult to have an exact representation of the frequency analysis. If the most occuring letter is not "*E*", then you can move on to the second-most common letter (which would be the letter "*T*")

#### Other / similar techniques:

1. **Double-letter-words:** Another technique you could try is to find all the words that have repeating letters, for your example that would be the last word "*cheers*". I *think* that in the English language the most common double-letter-words have 2 "*L*" in them, like "*kill*". But again this would fail, since here the double-letter-word is "*cheers*".
2. **Word-frequency-analysis:** You can also do a frequency analysis for whole words instead of single letters. Again, for the English language, this would be the word "*the*". For a long text you would expect that the word "*the*" would show up most often.

---

As you can see most of these common techniques would fail for your cipher-text. So the best technique you can use is brute-force.

Comment: It's not a Caesar shift: if E goes to V, F has to go to W, but W is a plain D here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I corrected the answer.