# Ciphers based on Keywords

Tags: encryption, stream-cipher, classical-cipher

I am looking for different ciphers that use a key word (like "hello" or "awesome") to encrypt a given text. I know about the Keyword Cipher already; I'm looking for others.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?): https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3826/possible-ways-to-crack-simple-hand-ciphers

Comment: Can you clarify if you are looking for pencil-and-paper ciphers or if this is a more general question? A string can always be hashed to a fixed-length bit vector, that can be used as a key for any block or stream cipher.

Comment: This is more general, @FrankDenis. It can be pencil-and-paper but I liked that second idea. Can you tell me more?

Comment: Note that modern ciphers require a key rather than a keyword / password. Hence you'd first pass the password through a Password Based Key Derivation Function (PBKDF) to stretch the key - i.e. make it harder to guess the password. Afterwards any secure cipher will do.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes How do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the Vigenere, or here is a complete list of keyword ciphers:
All the ciphers listed here are based on keys, but could be a little difficult to use. Some include making the keyword into a numerical sequence. By numbering each letter according to their place in the alphabet. If a letter appears twice, number them left to right.

i.e.
CAESAR =
314526

Comment: Sorry, here is the link:

Comment: http://www.cryptogram.org/resource-area/cipher-types/

Comment: Tip: You can use the "edit" link beneath your answer to make changes to it